# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to execute the following query and parameters in PHP PDO:

Query:

```
$query = " 
            UPDATE converts SET
                client_status = :client_status,
                date_client = :date_client,
                credit_status = :credit_status,
                credit = :new_credit,
                convert_type_sub = :convert_type_sub,
                system_status = :system_status
            WHERE
                external_key = :external_key AND
                client_username = :client_username AND
                client_status = :client_status_old";
```

Parameters:

```
$parameters = array(
                ":client_status" => "ACCEPTED",
                ":client_status_old" => "NOTHING",
                ":date_client" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                ":external_key" => DT($_POST["ek"]),
                ":client_username" => $_SESSION['user']['username'],
                ":credit_status" => "TAKEN",
                ":convert_type_sub" => "OCR",
                ":system_status" => "READY_FOR_DOCX",
                ":new_credit" => ($need + $row['credit']));
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR: UPDATE converts SET client_status = :client_status, date_client = :date_client, credit_status = :credit_status, credit = :new_credit, convert_type_sub = :convert_type_sub, system_status = :system_status WHERE external_key = :external_key AND client_username = :client_username AND client_status = :client_status_old
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

I spent two hours on the query and parameters but couldn't figure out what is the problem! Where I miss something?

Comment: I couldn't find any parameter which have same pointer so it's not duplicated.

Comment: `$parameters = array(
                ":client_status" => "ACCEPTED",
                ":date_client" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                ":credit_status" => "TAKEN",
                ":new_credit" => ($need + $row['credit']),
                ":convert_type_sub" => "OCR",
                ":system_status" => "READY_FOR_DOCX",
                ":external_key" => DT($_POST["ek"]),
                ":client_username" => $_SESSION['user']['username'],
                ":client_status_old" => "NOTHING");` check through this

Comment: @Anant Thank you but what is the difference? didn't you just reordered parameters? I tried it and got same error.

Comment: you have  to check that  `external_key" => DT($_POST["ek"]),` and  ":client_username" => $_SESSION['user']['username'],  and ":new_credit" => ($need + $row['credit']));   the variables you used in these are set and have some values